# How to create a webmap showing point density?

Tags: web-mapping, heat-map

I am trying to develop hotspot map showing point density in our GIS based web application.

After searching for an option I have decided to use v.kernel command. I have a table containing some point data i.e. crime data. I need to display the hotspot of crime for a particular area.

In v.kernel vector file containing points and polygon are used for displaying hotspots/heatmaps. In QGIS there is an option for selecting some rows and exporting it to shapefile. Is there any option for running this command from a Python file or is there any better option for displaying hotspot/heatmaps?

I have tried OpenLayers heatmap, Python's heatmap and django-heat app but nothing seems to work for me. I am using OpenLayers TMS (Openlayers-2.12) for displaying maps generated through Mapnik and TileCache.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your vector point data as a layer in QGIS, then changing the layer's renderer to Heatmap. If you then install the QGIS plugin qgis2web, and run it, it will try to generate a heatmap webmap for you. The heatmap functionality of qgis2web has not been heavily tested or used, as far as I'm aware, but it would be worth trying. I'd be very interested to hear your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextgis connect](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/) plugin to export the QGIS layer with symbology to your own Web GIS in [NextGIS Cloud](http://nextgis.com/) and create web map automatically.

See help pages: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/ngqgis_connect.html

[image]